# C# : Retrieve array values from bson document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In my MongoDB collection, I have a document with an array entry. How do I get these array values as a string array in C#? I can get the document itself back fine but I can't seem to get the array values. This is where I'm up to :

```
QueryDocument findUser = new QueryDocument("_id" , id);
BsonDocument user = bsonCollection.FindOne(findUser);
```

So in this `user` document, there is an array that I'd like to get and parse into a string array. The document looks something like this :

```
{
  "firstname" : "jon",
  "secondname" : "smith",
  "loves" : ["this","that","other stuff"]
}
```

Comment: a sample document would be nice for question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I got your problem correctly, One approach is :

```
var queryString = Query.EQ("_id", id);
var resultBsons = collection.FindOne(queryString);
var arrayOfStrings = resultBsons["loves"].AsBsonArray.Select(p => p.AsString).ToArray();
```