# How to fetch a list of values from a Bson document?

Tags: c#, json, list, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I'm parsing in a Json document that stores a list of type `<Country>` (which holds the `name` and `code`), using the [MongoDB.Net driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/?jmp=docs&_ga=1.75729237.13401923.1446400219). But I'm not sure how to retrieve that list of countries from the Bson document.

I stepped through the parsing code, all values are being parsed in to the CountryModel. Then stored in the returned `collection` var.

Googling brought me [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047165/c-sharp-retrieve-array-values-from-bson-document) but it only shows how to return a record by ID not a complete List. I'm wondering if a Lambda overload can be used here to find the list.

So far I've managed to retrieve the complete doc, and assign it to a list :

```
countries = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Does anyone know how I can fetch just `List<Country>` and not the whole document?

The two main methods involved in retrieving the data are as follows:

```
    public void LoadDb()
    {
        var collection = StartConnection();          
        countries = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }


    public IMongoCollection<CountryModel> StartConnection()
    {            
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("orders");
        //Get a handle on the countries collection:
        var collection = database.GetCollection<CountryModel>("countries");
        return collection;
    }
```

This is a sample of the Json data that's parsed in:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "565f5d3ae4b0ed465284d17a"
    },
    "countries": [
        {
            "name": "Afghanistan",
            "code": "AF"
        },
        {
            "name": "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "code": "AG"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the backing POCO class, `CountryModel` :

```
namespace MongoDBApp.Models
{
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class CountryModel
    {

        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("countries")]
        public List<Country> countries { get; set; }



    }

    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class Country
    {
        [BsonElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to return the countries subdocument across all of your documents in one array?

Comment: I'm looking to return all the countries in the country sub document as a list or array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with projection:

```
 var result = await collection.Find(x => x.Id == {ObjectId}).Project(x => x.countries).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Where *{ObjectId}* is the id of the CountryModel from which you want to fetch the countries collection.

Btw: There is more convenient way for using `ObjectId`. You can place `string` in your model and add attributes:

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Then you can use `Find` with Id in `string`:

```
 collection.Find(x => x.Id == "sample_object_id")
```

Comment: so I tried the following but the result is null when I set a breakpoint:  var result = await collection.Find(x => x.CountryObjectName == "countryObjName").Project(x => x.Countries).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                countryList = result;  Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you added CountryObjectName to the CountryModel, right? Are you sure in your database exists CountryModel with expected name? You can check it from mongo shell with command: 

db.CountryModel.find( { CountryObjectName : "countryObjName" } )

Or using tools like [MongoVUE](http://www.mongovue.com/)

Comment: ok so the "countryObjName" has to equal the string value for that field in my db? I thought it was just a placeholder value.This is the actual string value "CountryListObject" .I'll try changing to that and report back.

Comment: Yes, string "countryObjName" should be replaced by the real name of the CountryModel which contains countries list, from your database.

Comment: Ok I then assigned that result to a List<Country> but when I return it and try to convert to an Observable collection using this extension method I can't because it's now a Task<ObservableCollection<T>> Any idea how to modify my current extension method to accept that type? http://hastebin.com/ohiqafudon.vala

Comment: GetAllAsync() seems to be asynchronous :). Use `async` in method signature and `await` before converting to observable collection.

    `var result = await _customerDataService.GetAllAsync();
    Customers =  result.ToObservableCollection();`